# С помощью Stream api Java объединить элементы двух коллекций друг-с-другом

Tags: java, java-stream

Есть 2 коллекции: `c1 = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C")` и `c2 = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3")`. Подскажите, как с помощью Stream API на Java в 1 строку сделать коллекцию `{"A1", "B2", "C3"}`?

Answer (score 4):

В стандартных стримах почему-то нет операции `zip`, поэтому приходится прибегать к разврату типа

```
IntStream
  .range(0, Math.min(c1.size(), c2.size()))
  .mapToObj(i -> c1.get(i) + c2.get(i))
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Но `zip` есть в [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)

```
Streams
  .zip(c1.stream(), c2.stream(), (x, y) -> x + y)
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

И в [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/)

```
StreamEx.of(c1)
        .zipWith(StreamEx.of(c2), (x, y) -> x + y)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```